# Retrieving data from Oracle based on a date field

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I've done this plenty of times with SQL Server, just having some trouble with this one where my data is in Oracle.

What I'm doing is retrieving data from an Oracle Procedure and trying to bring it in to a DataGrid in C#.  My code is as such:

```
OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand();
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "CST_AMR_PNDSOURCEDOCS";
cmd3.Connection = conn;

string stDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", txtPendStartDt.Text);
string enDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", txtPendEndDt.Text);

cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("PndStDt", OracleType.DateTime).Value = stDate;
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("PndEnDt", OracleType.DateTime).Value = enDate;
cmd3.Parameters.Add("cursor_", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
var ds = new DataSet();
SearchAdapter.Fill(ds, "tblOpenStatus");

DataGrid_AdminRpt.DataSource = ds;
DataGrid_AdminRpt.DataBind();
```

I've got textboxes in asp.net with a RegularExpressionValidator on them:

```
<td style="width:120px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPendStartDt" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="stdtValid" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPendStartDt"
                ErrorMessage="X" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td>
<td style="width:120px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPendEndDt" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="endtValid" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPendEndDt"
                ErrorMessage="X" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td>
```

When I run this, I get an error on the `SearchAdapter.Fill(ds, "tblOpenStatus")` line:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at line 1

The dates I'm entering are 01/01/2010 and 03/20/2017.

Comment: Is the asp.net code relevant for the question? Cant you replace that with valid date to test it? My guess is you aren't using the standard ISO format for date `YYYY/MM/DD`

Comment: Well, I substituted my StDate and EnDate with hardcoded values (i.e.  string stDate = "1/1/2015";) and it still errored with the same error message.  On the Oracle side, the fields have a datatype of Date.  I'm still new to Oracle, I've got to be overlooking something.

Comment: again try with ISO format `2015/01/01`

Answer (score 0):

Don't send text to a date field. You should try to parse your string to date first. **[DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
 DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(enteredString);
```